# LOCATION in Hive

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveddl

While creating hive tables, Can I point the 'LOCATION' to a place in hdfs where data is present. Do I still need to load data or Will the data be available on hive directly?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify any location while creating table and the data will be accessible. If table is partitioned, then use `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` or `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name` or Amazon version `ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS` , this will add any partitions that exist on HDFS but not in metastore to the metastore. See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

If table is not partitioned, you can simply specify the location with data while creating table or change table location using `ALTER TABLE SET LOCATION`.